# click and choose only one button in LinearLayout android studio

Tags: android, android-button

I'm working on my first app and I got stuck.

I was wondering how is it possible to choose only one button at a time when all are in the same linear layout?
Also, when it was selected - to change the color of the selected button.

For example, in the screenshot below I uploaded you can see the 4 buttons in the same layout.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you change the buttons for radio group, and make a drawable for the selected states? I think it could be the best approach

Comment: You need a List<Button> and on all click listener you iterate all others and set unselected state and for the one clicked you set a selected state (like chaning background and text size/color)

Comment: @Rudy_TM
Can I mix, regular buttons with radio group?

Comment: You should post your relevant code of what you've tried here

Comment: @EliranLiriElgozi no only radio buttons, but you can give them listeners when they change, and in that way you always have only one selected.

Comment: @Rudy_TM

Well, I want to avoid using radio buttons since I find them not appealing to my taste.

is there and other way?

Comment: I used [ToggleButtons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton) inside of a `RadioGroup` years ago to achieve the same thing. Then obviously have a style file that handles the state of the button.

Comment: I ended up using @Rudy_TM idea and used radio buttons.

Comment: Nice :) can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with radioGroup  and radioButtons as a solution.

Worked like a charm.